# SignIn returns successfull but User is not

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-client-side

I have an Blazor WASM application. I use the Identity Framework for login with:

```
SignInResult signInResult = await signInManager<ApplicationUser>.PasswordSignInAsync(parameters.UserName, parameters.Password, parameters.RememberMe, true);
```

The `signInResult` is always `Succeeded`.

In the StateProvider in WebAssembly I get a UserInfo object which among other things tells if the user is Authenticated:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public UserInfoDto UserInfo()
    {
        return BuildUserInfo();
    }

    private UserInfoDto BuildUserInfo()
    {
        var userInfo = new UserInfoDto
        {
            IsAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated,
            UserName = User.Identity.Name
        };

        foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
        {
            userInfo.ExposedClaims.Add(claim.Type, claim.Value);
        }

        if (userInfo.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            userInfo.Id = Guid.Parse(identityService.GetUserId(User));
        }

        return userInfo;
    }
```

Here `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always false. I also checked it right after the PasswordSignInAsync but there it is the same as well.

My startup is setup this way:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationIdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SupportToolContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;

            // Lockout settings
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(LOCKOUT_DURATION);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = MAX_TRIES_BEFORE_LOCKOUT;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // Email Settings
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        });

// Configure LifeSpan of Identity email tokens
services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(3);
        });

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
            options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                             {
                                 OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                                                     {
                                                         context.Response.StatusCode = UNAUTHORIZED_STATUS_CODE;
                                                         return Task.CompletedTask;
                                                     }
                             };
        });
```

And the Configure method contains:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

AuthenticationStateProvider:

public class IdentityAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        private UserInfoDto userInfoCache;
        private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

```
    public IdentityAuthenticationStateProvider(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    ..

    private async Task<UserInfoDto> GetUserInfoAsync()
    {
        var authorizeApi = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAuthorizeApi>();

        if (userInfoCache != null && userInfoCache.IsAuthenticated) return userInfoCache;
        userInfoCache = await authorizeApi.GetUserInfoAsync();

        return userInfoCache;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        try
        {
            UserInfoDto userInfo = await GetUserInfoAsync();
            if (userInfo.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                IEnumerable<Claim> claims = new[] {new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userInfoCache.UserName)}.Concat(
                    userInfoCache.ExposedClaims.Select(c => new Claim(c.Key, c.Value)));
                identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Server authentication");
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Request failed:" + ex);
        }

        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
    }
}
```

In general the whole process is identical to this example: https://github.com/stavroskasidis/BlazorWithIdentity
(which stopped working locally as well)

What confuses me is that it worked before and still does on the server and it doesn't work locally if I checkout that history at the point deployed to the server. What do I miss?

Comment: You use User.Identity.IsAuthenticated on Blazor WebAssembly, right ? If so, how do you get the User object, where do you get it from?

Comment: No, in the StateProvider in Blazor WASM I request the user infos from the server. In the Controller Endpoint I make the call for IsAuthenticated. I updated my post to describe that better.

Comment: OK, @NPadrutt, I saw the sample. In principal, it is something similar to what I've suggested. It's really difficult to say what is wrong with your code without seeing and testing it all. Perhaps you forgot to copy some settings, for example. Check if your Client.Startup class contains all the code from the sample

Comment: That was the idea with the sample, since it has the exact same issue as my project has. And the code regarding authentication is identitcal as far as I can see.
Also, I did my best to post all relevant code parts, but let me know if there is anything I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, this is frustrating. The solution was to reboot all my computer. It seems that the issue was somewhere in IIS Express or so - on both my computer simultaneously.

Comment: Mark this as the answer :)

Comment: I have to wait two days since it is my own answer, but I'll do that then :)